# Is there a webhook in DAML SDK that can gather data on created transactions

Tags: daml

The ledger API allows us to pull data on demand but is there a service that pushes data like analytics when there are new transactions pertaining to a threshold or search criteria or just aggregate functions based on transaction data.

Comment: Hi Balaji, thanks for the question? Do you think you can be slightly more thorough in your formulation? Am I right in understanding that you'd like to subscribe to aggregations of events based on a query? If that's so, do you think you can maybe include an example of the behavior you'd like to see? Pseudo-code works fine.

Answer (score 3):

The Ledger API allows you to stream transactions that are created on the ledger using gRPC. Using any gRPC-generated client you can implement a filter, transformation or aggregation over transactions in your code. The protobuf definition of the service endpoint to connect to is this:

```proto
service TransactionService {

    // Read the ledger's filtered transaction stream for a set of parties.
    rpc GetTransactions (GetTransactionsRequest) returns (stream GetTransactionsResponse);

}
```

In Java for example subscribing to the transaction stream would then look like this:

```java
public class Main {

    private static void processTransaction(TransactionOuterClass.Transaction tx) {
        // process (filter, transform, aggregate) transaction
        System.out.printf("received transaction %s\n", tx.getTransactionId());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a GRPC channel
        ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 7600).usePlaintext().build();

        // Get ledger identity
        LedgerIdentityServiceBlockingStub ledgerIdService = LedgerIdentityServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
        GetLedgerIdentityResponse identityResponse = ledgerIdService.getLedgerIdentity(GetLedgerIdentityRequest.getDefaultInstance());
        String ledgerId = identityResponse.getLedgerId();

        // Subscribe observer to transaction stream
        String party = "Alice";
        TransactionServiceStub transactionService = TransactionServiceGrpc.newStub(channel);
        GetTransactionsRequest transactionsRequest = GetTransactionsRequest.newBuilder()
                .setLedgerId(ledgerId)
                .setBegin(LedgerOffset.newBuilder().setBoundary(LedgerOffset.LedgerBoundary.LEDGER_BEGIN))
                .setFilter(TransactionFilter.newBuilder().putFiltersByParty(party, Filters.getDefaultInstance()))
                .build();
        StreamObserver<GetTransactionsResponse> transactionObserver = new StreamObserver<GetTransactionsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(GetTransactionsResponse value) {
                value.getTransactionsList().forEach(Main::processTransaction);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                System.err.printf("%s encountered an error while processing transactions!\n", party);
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                System.out.printf("%s's transactions stream completed.\n", party);
            }
        };
        System.out.printf("%s starts reading transactions.\n", party);
        transactionService.getTransactions(transactionsRequest, transactionObserver);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is using the raw GRPC-generated code. There are also reactive bindings available in the SDK, which make the above less verbose.